# How to Grant Permissions to LocalService account?

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2016

I have a Service that should Log into Eventlog via Log4Net. This is not working, because I assume it to lack the permissions. Lately I had the same issue with an IIS App that was run by `ApplicationPoolIdentity`. To Fix this Issue, I had to grant `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` Permissions to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog`.

As the Service uses the `Local Systemaccount`, I wanted to grant it these permissions.

[image]

I get the following Error:

> The following Object is invalid, because it is not part of the given Searchdomain: NT AUTHORITY\LocalService
>
> Original Message in German: 
> *Das folgende Objekt ist ungültig, da es nicht Teil der angegebenen Suchdomäne ist:
> NT AUTHORITY\LocalService*

Comment: I can get Local Service to pass the Check Names test if I select "Entire Directory" in the "From this location:" field, and type "Local Service" (note the space between the words) in the "Enter the object names to select" field. Can you try that?

Comment: Also, can you clarify what account the service is using? You mention the Local System account in the second paragraph, but you are trying to grant permissions to the Local Service account.

Comment: @doug You are right. The Service User is called "Lokales System" which translates into `LocalSystem` or on some Webpages is called `NT Authority\SYSTEM`. But apparently i get the same error when adding these accounts. Maybe the names are different with the german language settings?

Comment: Local System should already have Full Control access to that registry location. But if it does not, you can add it by entering `System` in the "Enter the object names to select" field. Can you edit your question to include screenshots of the error you get when trying it with the `System` account?

Comment: Well entering `System` worked. Don't know why `NT Authority\SYSTEM` wasn't found. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great! I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local System should already have Full Control access to that registry location. But if it does not, you can add it by entering `system` in the "Enter the object names to select" field. Then click on the Check Names button.

[image]

That will then validate what you entered, and, if successful, will change the display to an underlined and all-caps `SYSTEM`.

[image]

(I was able to do this with either my local workstation or `Entire Directory` selected in the "From this location" field.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know why it won't accept `NT Authority\SYSTEM`?

Comment: I don't know why, but these two questions have answers that describe some of the concepts around `NT Authority\System` and `LocalSystem`. Perhaps those questions and answers will shed some light on your particular case. https://superuser.com/questions/1067246/is-nt-authority-system-a-user-or-a-group https://superuser.com/questions/471769/what-is-the-nt-authority-system-user/471774

Comment: Awesome! It really helped growing my understanding of this topic. Thanks for sharing it here.